# Draw ellipse to form failing

Tags: c#, graphics

Using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287520(v=vs.71).aspx) as a reference I tried drawing an ellipse to my form which is not showing at my own custom coordinates.

Thus I copied over the code from the example directly and it is still not showing (tried on a new project with a blank form). I have gone through the page and am sure I have not missed anything.

Code from MSDN

```
System.Drawing.SolidBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
formGraphics.FillEllipse(myBrush, new Rectangle(0,0,200,300));
myBrush.Dispose();
formGraphics.Dispose();
```

Is there an `onPaint` method or a related method not mentioned that I should be using/ be aware of?

Answer (score 0):

The code works flawlessly when I do it like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.SolidBrush myBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red);
        System.Drawing.Graphics formGraphics = panel1.CreateGraphics();
        formGraphics.FillEllipse(myBrush, new Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 300));
        myBrush.Dispose();
        formGraphics.Dispose();
    }
```

But I created the graphics on a panel, I tend to do this when working with graphics.

The code above does NOT work when put in the `Form_Load` event.  It also does not "draw" on any portion of the form that does not exist yet (if you draw in area that out of the bounds of the form, then stretch the form, the new stretched area will not have a drawing on it.)

Here is the image of my results when the code is placed in the click event:

[image]

Where are you putting this code?

Comment: Heh, seems we were both working on that at the same time and posted seconds apart.   I'm going to post an edit to yours and delete my entry.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I should of mentioned the Form_Load, he is probably asking for it to draw after the form opens.

Comment: Also, another method of drawing after the form loads is by using the Form_Shown() method rather than the Form_Load(), in our case we used a button, because that also is guaranteed to be performed after the Form has completely loaded.

Comment: While this does paint some pixels the result is non-persistent and will disappear as soon as you resize or mimimize the form or... - So this is basically the __wrong__ way to to draw __anything but__ stuff that is __meant__ to disappear immediately. - Since The OP even asks for the `OnPaint` method I suggest dropping the crappy MSDN example and moving the code to the `Paint` event of the Form using its `e.Graphics` object!